# pfgplots - How to include graphic at specific place

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

MWE which creates a pgfplot:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{width=15cm,height = 7cm, compat=1.9}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ylabel={Unemployment (millions)},
xlabel={Year},
xmin=2000, xmax=2017,
ymin=10, ymax=26,
xtick={2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016},
x tick label style={rotate=90},
ytick={10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26},
xmajorgrids=true,
ymajorgrids=true,
grid style=dashed,
]
\end{axis}
% \node at (6.65,3.1) {\includegraphics[width = 13.3cm, height= 5.3cm]{19mj_33_21.pdf}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I draw your attention to this line:

```
\node at (6.65,3.1) {\includegraphics[width = 13.3cm, height= 5.3cm]{19mj_33_21.pdf}};
```

Right now, I have hardcoded it to place it where I want. How can I do so with reference to the x and y-axis value I have defined?

Specifically, I want the bottom-left corner of the diagram to start at `(2000,10)` (my x-axis goes from 2000 to 2016, my y-axis goes from 10 to 26).

Comment: Maybe this question answers your problem? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz

Comment: `\node [anchor=south west,inner sep=0] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width = 13.3cm, height= 5.3cm]{19mj_33_21.pdf}};`

Comment: Dial a higher version, e.g. `compat=1.16` but at least `compat=1.11`, or use `axis cs:` coordinates.

Comment: Or put the node inside the axis environment should even work.